# Why does nrow() return a NULL value?

Tags: r, dataframe, rows, na

In writing code for a function, I have selected complete cases from the 2nd column of a data frame with 4 columns called "myData" and confirmed that 117 of >1700 rows have been selected into "mycases" by printing those values. The selection code is:

```
mycases <- myData[complete.cases(myData[,2]),2]
```

I can sum the values of these 117 cases successfully, but when I try to count them using code:

```
fkount <- nrow(mycases)
```

R returns NULL. What I am doing wrong? Is there some easier way to get the number of cases?

Comment: what is the result of `dim(mycases)`? Consider also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

`mycases` is in your case a vector. If you want to know its length use `length(mycases)`.

I guess you want something like this.

```
library(dplyr)
myData <- data.frame(A = c(1:3, NA), B = c(1,NA,2,NA))
myData %>% filter(complete.cases(.)) %>% nrow()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you extract a single column from your data frame (or from a matrix), it is by default converted into a vector, and `nrow` does not work on vectors (since they don't have rows + columns).

You have (at least) 2 options:

1. use `length()` instead.  This will work, but has the risk that if you use the same code later to extract 2 (or more) columns, it will now give a probably-undesired result: either the *total* length of an extracted matrix (all the elements), or the number of *columns* of an extracted data frame.
2. use the `drop=FALSE` argument of `[ ]`.  This will prevent conversion of a single column into a vector, and it will remain a 2d object (but with `ncol` equal to 1).  Then `nrow` will work as you intend.

Example:

```
mydata=data.frame(matrix(1:100,ncol=5))

# using length()
length( mydata[,2] ) 
# 20
# but watch out!
length( mydata[,2:3] )
# 2

# using drop=FALSE
nrow( mydata[,2,drop=FALSE] )
# 20
# safer:
nrow( mydata[,2:3,drop=FALSE] )
# 20
```